# How to get to this quest marker in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm on top of the mountain, the sign says it's below me, but there's nothing but snow on either side of the mountain. A cave perhaps, but where?

[image]

Comment: If it's the same place I'm thinking of, you get to it via a cave, but I managed to glitch up the side of the mountain with some luck. It took me like 10 minutes though of careful movement.

Comment: For future, this has nothing to do with the witcher (the furst game), so qe do not use the tag. Furthermore, limit yourself to the suggested tags (as you type), aswe do not want junk rags created, as was in this case. -1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not quite clear where you are but I think that is one of the locations you will get to during the 'The Sunstone' quest late in the main story. There is a entrance to a big cave system on the coast but it is sealed until the quest starts.

Alternatively it might be the marker for an underground location in the 'King's Gambit' quest line (this marker is just north of Kaer Trolde).

There are several markers in Skellige you can only reach as part of quests.

Comment: I can confirm this answer. I recognize this spot and running around looking for an entrance for 20 minutes only to get access to it late in the storyline.